# Which property value gets assigned in this scenario?

Tags: spring, yaml, application.properties

I'm working in a project with multiple sources of properties. The main sources are profile-specific, i.e., application.properties, application-*dev*.properties, etc.

There are also yaml files which contain documents for each profile.

I can't run this project using any profile but dev, so I can't answer this for myself right now:

**application.properties**

`my.prop=a`

**application-prod.properties**

`my.prop=b`

**other.yaml**

```
reference:
     prop: ${my.prop}
```

Given an active profile of **prod**, then what will the value be in the application context for the **reference.prop** property? The yaml file only has a default document, so will it pull from the default .properties or the prod?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'b'. I don't know why I assumed running on dev would be any different from prod. reference.prop is referencing a property key in another file, the value of which is set by the active profile, so effectively, the default value in the yaml file is tied to how the referenced value is defined. That's my take on it, at least.